# What should we do with Tor Onion links in questions?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation, ethics

I just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76649198/tor-python-scraper-on-jupyter-notebooks) question and I wondered something like that *should be allowed*, although asking it this way sounds a bit weird. The user wants to scrape sites in the [Tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29) network and posted some example sites, e.g. their onion links.

It seems quite common for questions to include a site’s link, if a specific issue around working with that site is the subject of the question. People who want to answer may take a look at them to figure things out.

However in the case of onion links, this seems to be *potentially problematic*, as the names of the links don't reveal much or no information at all about their subject, which may be an important (yet normally not thought about) filter for a user’s decision to open the link. If someone asked my help regarding an issue with *madeupwebpresenseofonlinedrugmarket.co*, I'd likely turn to another question. Then again, the name doesn't have to be revealing.

I'm undecided what to think about it. On one hand, people are smart enough to be aware of the potential issue of unwillingly opening some online criminal market; on the other hand, some people may not be that aware.

What's the right way to deal with that? Or is there no need *to deal* with that?

**Quick edit**
I hope it's clear that I don't want to shame the Tor Network, which is doing an important job for freedom of press and so on.

Comment: I guess [How do we handle questions that are potentially or blatantly illegal or malicious?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267699) applies here as well. Also, that question looks like a request for a lib, thus not on-topic anyway.

Comment: It seems odd that the question needs to contain any actual tor links.

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow curators need to treat `somesiteiveneverheardof.com` differently from `somesiteiveneverheardof.onion` (or, more precisely, from `56-random-characters.onion`). While it's true that the risk of something questionable is higher for an onion link, anyone looking at such a question should treat both with the same initial skepticism - and a question worth keeping around should not require the link for viewers to make sense of it anyway.

Comment: As you can't follow the link unless you're already set up and using Tor, there really isn't much risk.

Comment: Given that [link shorteners are banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shortening-services) I'd say the same rules apply for the same reasons (link rot, possible malicious sites,...)

Comment: @JanDoggen By what logic are links to websites on a different protocol (Tor) the same as URL shorteners?

Comment: just for the record, all 3 onion links posted on the linked question, they point to TOR search engines (tordex, ahmia, torch)

Comment: @JanDoggen onion links don't rot by the link shortener becoming unavailable

Comment: Slightly related (we can't have nice things and freedom of press): *[Update on the ongoing DDoS attacks and blocking Tor exit nodes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376060/update-on-the-ongoing-ddos-attacks-and-blocking-tor-exit-nodes)*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> It seems quite common for questions to include a site’s link, if a specific issue around working with that site is the subject of the question. People who want to answer may take a look at them to figure things out.

My position is that website URLs cannot be a component of a proper MRE, so the point is moot. People who really demand that the question address a specific URL rather than an *underlying issue* are looking for a help desk, not Stack Overflow.

If the "issue working with a site" is actually idiosyncratic to that site, and can't be demonstrated by any of a bunch of other sites, then it's off topic here - it's a tech support question for the site's operators.

On the other hand, if it's something that only affects certain sites, but is found in multiple places (e.g. "why doesn't tool X scrape such and such content?" "because it's inserted dynamically using JavaScript, and tool X only processes the original HTML"), then a proper example needs to identify *what* the issue is, not *who* provides data that causes the issue. Ideally that would look something like a hypothetical HTML document abridged to a MRE (or a hypothetical HTTP response, depending on the kind of issue); but in practice, canonicals like [How can I scrape a page with dynamic content (created by JavaScript) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520) are more than good enough.

Comment: "then a proper example needs to identify what the issue is, not who provides data that causes the issue" - the problem with that is that it often requires understanding the problem or the solution (if any) which means there would not be a question in the first place. So, yeah, I'm with most of your reasoning, but I think there is a place for questions where people need pointers translating their "problem with website XYZ" into "the problem with servers that don't implement ABC" or "how do I support DEF".

Comment: is MRE "minimum reproducible example"? Took me a while to understand, you may want to expand when it's not already defined in the question for example

Comment: "the problem with that is that it often requires understanding the problem or the solution (if any) which means there would not be a question in the first place" Sure. Sometimes people who have a question aren't capable of asking the question they really have. That's an issue with the original design and conception of Stack Overflow, not a reason to change how the site operates. We redirect, close or fix questions that don't meet standards, so that we have ones that do; and over time canonicals become more discoverable by people with the underlying issue.

Comment: @Luc on the main site, "[mre]" is the short code for a link to the [corresponding documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so I tend to consider it part of the jargon Meta users are expected to be familiar with.

Answer (score 15):

In context, there are two things you need to keep in mind.

- **You are not law enforcement of any kind, and you do not need to operate as such.** Seeing someone post a link to something dodgy is about all the ceremony you need to give here:  "Oh, that link looks dodgy."  Don't click dodgy links or try to investigate what the link actually does.  For the sake of Q&A, *that does not matter.*
- **Take the question at face value.** What's actually being asked here is if someone has a scraper that can scrape websites.  Doesn't really matter if it's on the World Wide Web or if it's a hidden service, the question itself is problematic *because they want us to **provide** them with a suitable scraper.*

What do you need to do? Deal with the question as you normally would if someone was asking us to provide them a general-purpose library for their needs.  Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 5):

If you find a suspicious link, flag the post for moderator attention. This is important as editing a post doesn't completely remove the link; it still could be found by looking at the post-revision history.

If the link looks innocuous, remember that questions should be self-contained. If a link to an external resource is not required to understand the question and provide proper attribution, then it's noise; from the perspective of only questions and answers, no chit-chat, it doesn't matter where the link points; if it's not required and doesn't provide any value, remove it.

P.S. A sister site is specialized in Tor: [Tor Stack Exchange](https://tor.stackexchange.com). I'm not familiar with this community. I wonder if they might help to know if a tor link is dangerous.

Comment: I've looked through a few sites of their questions and it seems they don't usually post onion links. Maybe they do from time to time, though. **My issue is a bit** How do you know a link is suspicious? Actually never until you open it, but at least a regular one indicates something (which can ofc be misleading) before making that decision.

Comment: @srn As I mentioned in the answer, if you are not familiar with Tor onion links, flag it for moderator attention. P.S. If you want to learn if a Tor onion link is dangerous, you might look into [tor.se] and [security.se]. Probably [su], [ubuntu.se], [unix.se] and [apple.se]  might help with questions about how to keep safe while navigating across the Internet.

Comment: "*if not required and doesn't provide any value, remove it*" That sounds like a threshold that can usually be argued to be met, since questions and answers are self-contained. We could remove most links from stackexchange! If they contained value, the info ought to have been in the question or answer. | Rather, I would say that onion links are no different from normal links and can be treated the same, with perhaps the addition that if a clearweb version of the link is available, it should be added *in addition* for convenience (but not replace, because onion sites have advantages).

Comment: @Luc: It's normal for answers especially to link things for further reading as optional bonus material that goes beyond the strict scope necessary to answer the specifics of the question.  So there's lots of room for there to be value in links even in posts that do answer the question without them.  Less often in questions, but linking an official doc they were trying to follow, or a tutorial that raised more questions than answers, can be helpful context to figure out how they got confused.  Or for [osdev] questions, [mcve]'s often aren't complete, so linking full code lets editors fix it.

Comment: We also leave links in place e.g. for citations.